# On IPad Mail, Inbox folder not displaying properly

Tags: ipad, mail.app, ipados

A bit hard to explain without the illustration attached, but on my iPad, using iCloud or Fastmail (so its not provider-related), it doesn’t display the inbox folder alongside my other folders for the account. Somehow it does display in the shortcuts/unified folder above. Even when editing the folder list it doesn’t give me the option to display below.

On my iPhone Mail app it works correctly. I’ve tried removing and re-adding the account as well. No idea why.

Model: iPad Pro 3rd gen
OS: iOS 16.3

[image]

Comment: It always helps to include the iPad model and iPadOS version to help us troubleshoot this. Please edit your question and add that to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need to do is to **long-click** on the mailbox you want to move (in this case "Drafts" in this case if I understood the screenshot well) and **drag** it to the desired place and then **drop** it. All of this **without clicking "Edit"**!
Hope this helps! :D